# Unable to login with Facebook , Gmail after shifting project to another environment

Tags: android

I have shifted my android project to different Laptop. I was able to login with facebook , login with gmail was perfectly fine when application was built with previous laptop. Now i am not able to login with these after building my current laptop. Application is in under development.  Only Firebase is working perfectly.

Please suggest me what to do now.

Comment: you need to regenerate and update hash keys for APIs on new laptop `keytool -exportcert -alias ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it related with your device `keyhash(FB) and sha1(google)` that you used while registering your app on facebook and google platform . these keys varies from device to device , basically unique. now you need to regenerate them on your new machine and reconfigure the project on facebook and google platform.
go to your project on google and facebook and follow the instructions to generate and then replace with previous one

Comment: my pleasure @Mr.Yasir Ameen